# Is there a way to disable the Wiki functionality / hide it completly in Redmine?

Tags: redmine

We would like to use a common Wiki for all our projects. For this purpose we use DokuWiki. Now there is still the module in Redmine shown with the Wiki functionality which creates often discussion in teams about which one to use. Is there a clean way to disable the Wiki functionality of Redmine completely?

Comment: Hi Ioomi, welcome to PMSE! Our site is more focused on questions about the field of project management, as tool-specific questions tends to be outdated in a very short period of time, which goes against the idea of the SO platform. Please check our [FAQ]. Thanks!

Comment: okay.. I had the impression to have found the right place here.. If so than back to stackoverflow, or serverfault for that matter. Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a quick and easy method to hide the wiki modul from the project module selection. I think this is what you want, right. Therefore, modify the redmine.rb file in the lib directory. This file is similar to the plugin's init.rb.

**< REDMINE_ROOT >/lib/redmine.rb**

Comment the section as shown below (on redmine 2.3.x it's starting at line 160) :

```
=begin
map.project_module :wiki do |map|
    map.permission :manage_wiki, {:wikis => [:edit, :destroy]}, :require => :member
[...]
    map.permission :protect_wiki_pages, {:wiki => :protect}, :require => :member
  end
=end
```

Using a patch or "patch-plugin" is much nicer than modifying the source, anyway it works.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

We use redmine at work and none of our projects have a wiki by default. You can set individual project menu components through the admin area - if memory serves, but you need admin rights.

You can also lock wikis (restrict access to certain members); however, I'm not sure if this will remove the menu link: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineWikis

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I gave it a upvote but as you say we look for a way to hide everything, also to the admins!